# How to find a character using index in PHP string?

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP code like this:

```
$string = "This is a PHP code";
```

I want to find a character at index 3 in above string. And output must be:

```
s
```

Is there any idea to achieve this goal ?

Comment: `echo $string[ 3 ];`

Comment: `substr($string, -3, 1)`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Sorry for poor quality question. I just search for $string.CharAt(3) like function. My mind was deep inside javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you want character at 3rd index then write following line ;)

```
echo $string[3];
```